# Issue in saving custom customer attributes after upgrading from 1.4.2 to 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, customer, upgrade

I have upgraded by website from magento ce 1.4.2 to magento ce 1.7.2, everything works fine but custom customer attributes in account edit page are not getting saved, I have added these attributes using my custom module.
What can be the probable issue. 
I have done a little debugging that shows I am not getting my custom attributes in `$this->_attributes;` in `getAttributes()` method.
Please let me know if anybody have any idea or someone faced any similar issue and what he/she have to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the issue, the problem was that attribute is not related to form.
I have added below code in upgrade script and all works fine.

```
$attr = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'attr_code');
$attr->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_customer'));
$attr->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

The update from 1.5 to 1.6 introduced some new columns for customer attributes.
Check `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php:665` for the column `is_visible`.
Take care that your attribute has this flag set to true.

Otherwise prepare an upgrade with something like:

```
$installer->updateAttribute(
    'customer',
    'your_attribute',
    'is_visible',
    1
);
```

Comment: I have checked, is_visible is set to true.

Comment: And also I can't see backend_model for my custom attributes in db, if it can be the probable issue, then please let me know how can I update my attributes to have a backend model.